# Potential PhD supervisor not responding after showing interests

Tags: phd, advisor, supervision

I contacted a professor to see if he would be interested to be my supervisor. He very quickly replied and indicated he was interested. He was very sincere in a way he even included a guideline to help me put together a research proposal so he could consider further. He also suggested where to find funding and mentioned I could let him know if I needed support.

Some time later I sent him my research proposal. It’s been around two weeks he hasn’t responded to me. So I very politely reached out again to see if he would still be interested with an amended proposal enclosed.

I know that now  I will only wait. And I will not write further because I don’t want to harass him. If he doesn’t reply does that mean a rejection? It seems quite strange - his initial response was sincere and positive, so I thought if he eventually finds the project unfit he would also notify me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have waited two weeks it is fine to send a short email now, saying something like "I just wanted to check that you received my proposal". After that, if you don't hear from them, you must assume it is a rejection. It wouldn't be a polite rejection on their part, but not everyone is polite.

Comment: Seems like thats the only thing I can do!

Answer (score -1):

> "He was very sincere in a way he even included a guideline to help me
> put together a research proposal so he could consider further.

did you consider the fact he had a pre-ready email with these guidelines and he minimally adapted to you?

Whit this I mean it was still a constructive and positive answer from him, it would even fit with the rather presumptuous "I have no time to answer, so no explicit answer means no".

There would be no harm in trying to reach him by phone to ask him a feedback, since he asked to share with him **your ideas**, it would be the minimum of decency from him to give you a feedback.
The worse it can happen is that he considers you annoying him ... and you do not want to work with such kind of person, so even the worse is a good outcome for you.

Comment: Thx! I agree with you - I did consider that part was 'copy-and-paste' contents. because there are two fonts type in one email. but either ways, if he did not feel interested he would not even bother to reply, and provide detailed guidelines (tho copied and pasted).
But you are right I might as well just skip to another professor.